# How to input 5D tensor to keras model.fit

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am utilizing tensorflow ver 2, tensorflow.keras.

A model I made is in a sequence of `tf.keras.Conv2D` ( which requires 4D input tensor (samples, rows, cols, channels)

then `tf.keras.convLSTM2D` (which requires 5D input tensor (samples, time, rows, cols, channels).

Because of this reason, I made an input with 5D tensor (samples, time, rows, cols, channels) but it can't be fed into tf.keras.Conv2D at the beginning when I implement `model.fit(train_data, train_data... )`

Is there any way to make model.fit to take 5D tensor?

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading, the problem is not about model.fit, its with you trying to input a 5D tensor to Conv2D, which won't work. Conv3D will accept your tensor with no issues.

Comment: You could use a Conv3D, and just keep the time axis stride and kernal at 1.

Comment: You shouldn't use conv3D in case of temporal conv2D network. TimeDistributed layer of Keras is made just for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `TimeDistributed` conv2D as in :

```py
x_conv = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters,
                                                                kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                                                strides=strides,
                                                                padding='same',
                                                                kernel_initializer='he_normal'))(x)
```

This way the layers understand that you're giving 4D input over `timestep`